# Textures in build duplicated, despite they're packed into atlases

Tags: unity, android, ios, texture-atlas, build-process

I have a simple `SpriteAtlas`: "UIAtlas" which is located in the `Resources` folder.
It points to a folder "UIAtlas" which contains my menu textures.

All of my batching is working perfectly, everything is being batched, because of the atlas.

When I build an iOS version, in the `Editor.log` I can see this:

> Build Report
>
> Uncompressed usage by category:
>
> **Textures 299.5 mb (30%)**
>
> Meshes 0.0kb (0%)
>
> ...
>
> Used Assets and files from the Resources folder, sorted by uncompressed size:
>
> **16.0 mb 1.6% Built-in Texture2D: sactx-2048x2048-Uncompressed-UIAtlas-312aba98**
>
> ...
>
> **345.3 kb 0.1% Assets/Resources/UIAtlas/medal.png**
>
> ... more entries like this ...

Please notice that this texture (medal.png), along with the other textures belongs to this atlas, which is already included in the build-executable.

I feel this is wrong.
If I pack things, they should be packed into that texture and only that 2048x2048 texture should be in the build, right?

What's wrong here?

Comment: Does this still happen if you move the source file out of the Resources directory?

Comment: Turned out that this is the issue. I found a post on Unity forums, made by one of the employees, explaining that any graphic in both the Resources folder and the SpriteAtlas will be duplicated. I'll find a link and put it here. Thanks, you were right ;)

Comment: Ooh, can you summarize that post as an answer here?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an [official answer](https://forum.unity.com/threads/sprite-atlas-and-sprites-in-resources-folder.596269/).

> Any assets inside the Resources folder (including Sprites and Atlases regardless of being packed) will always be exported. This is by design.

So when we make a `SpriteAtlas` with some textures, and put in it the `Resources` folder, it's a total mess. I did it initially cause I wanted to unload assets and load them dynamically.